# is go dependent on perl & sh?

Tags: go

I checked the [source code of the `syscall` package](https://golang.org/src/syscall/).

I found that there are files like mkall.sh, mkerrors.sh, mksyscall.pl, mksyscall_libc.pl etc.

It arouse the question - is go dependent on perl and sh?

Comment: It's dependent on perl and shell to do what those files do, which is generate some source files. The runtime is not dependent on those if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a shell to build Go itself. But your system already has some sort of shell, so that's not really relevant. You need Perl to regenerate some of the source files, but that's not something you would normally do even if building Go, as the files are already generated there.

You do not necessarily need them to build your own programs written in Go, though as mentioned already, you already have a shell of some sort.

Comment: You don't need perl to build Go, those scripts are for regenerating some source files.  You do need an existing Go install for bootstrapping and one of the supported shells to start the process.